# Using page slug in array

Tags: pages, slug

I want to use the page slug as the taxonomy when calling a list of custom posts.

This works:

```
<?php $page_slug = basename(get_permalink()); ?>
<?php echo  $page_slug; ?>
```

It shows "december-2017" on the page.

So does this:

```
<ul>
    <?php 
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'nomination',
            'post_status' => 'draft',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'month_category',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'december-2017',
                )
            )
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    ?>
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <?php the_terms( $post ->ID, 'dealership_category', '', '', '' ); ?><br>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br> 
        Submitted: <?php echo get_the_date( 'd/m/Y' ); ?>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li>Nothing found.</li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
```

So why can't I get this to work:

```
<ul>
<?php $page_slug = basename(get_permalink()); ?>

    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'nomination',
            'post_status' => 'draft',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'month_category',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => '$page_slug',
                )
            )
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    ?>
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <?php the_terms( $post ->ID, 'dealership_category', '', '', '' ); ?><br>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br> 
        Submitted: <?php echo get_the_date( 'd/m/Y' ); ?>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li>Test not working.3</li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
```

It shows "Test not working.3" on the page. I'm not great at PHP so am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your tax query, you're searching for a string instead of a variable, the only time it will match currently is if the term is literally "$page_slug". You should remove the single quotes around the `$page_slug` to have it parsed as a variable, so:

```
'terms' => '$page_slug'
```

should be:

```
 'terms' => $page_slug,
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting, I really appreciate your explanation as it's helping me learn. I did originally try it without the quote marks but it disn't work. I just tried it again and it works!